# Price is showing Unavailable in B2B commerce in System admin profile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

In Salesforce Commerce B2B after adding the price on product ,price is showing Unavailable in System admin profile but it is showing price in other profile user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of factors to consider here.

I would start investigating with:

1. The user you are using, does it belong to a buyergroup?
2. Does that buyergroup from question #1 has the correct entitlements?
3. Does that buyergroup from question #1 have the right pricebooks?
4. Does the pricebook attached to that buyer group from question #2 and #3 within a valid one? Start date and end date.